# Tomcat Workers - Connecting Tomcat and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, tomcat, mod-proxy-ajp

I'm trying to resolve an issue about connecting Apache-HTTPD and Tomcat with mod_proxy_ajp. From reading I found that the problem might be the number of workers in HTTPD and Tomcat. So I try to find the worker's definition in the Tomcat but I couldn't find any. Can it be? Can Tomcat work without a workers.properties file? I checked the imports in the Tomcat conf just to make sure that there isn't a different file name but found none. How can I find out the worker's configuration of my Tomcat setup? Is there a default?

The problem that I'm trying to solve is that in some cases the Tomcat stops responding to the Apache - in the Apache log I see many errors like:

```
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header
ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
(120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from 127.0.0.1:9005 (localhost)
```

So I'm trying to find out maybe the Apache has more workers than the Tomcat.

I'm using Apache 2.2.15 and Tomcat 7, connected with mod_proxy_ajp on a Redhat machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured a connector in your tomcat configuration for mod_proxy_ajp to connect to?  I know you have to do this when using mod_jk.

```
   <Connector port="45499" maxThreads="50" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

We do something like the above.

Comment: how i configure threads for mod_proxy_ajp? i couldnt find it in the documentation. could it be that its non configurable?

Comment: Beats me.  We use mod_jk for ajp access to our tomcats.  Like I said above, we have to configure the ajp connector with it's maxThreads in the tomcat.